# How do i structure a query where I am INSERTing into a new table and need to increment a column every time?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a table called Categories and each row has a primary key 'CategoryId'

Each row also has an int 'ParentId'. ParentId corresponds to another row in the table.  Multiple rows can have the same ParentId.

I have another table called 'CategoriesSort' where I have 3 columns; CategoryId, ParentId, Sort.

For every row that shares a ParentId in the Categories table, I want to add a row in the Sort table, and increment sort every time a row is added for that ParentId.

How do I structure this query?   I hate to post this question as is, because it seems like I am just asking someone to do my work for me, but I am actually struggling. so here is what I have so far.

```
INSERT INTO SOLCategoriesSort(CategoryId, ParentId, Sort)

SELECT CategoryId, ParentId
FROM SOLCategories
WHERE  CategoryId > 0 AND ParentId > 0 AND  ParentId IN (
    Select ParentId
    From SOLCategories
    Group by ParentId
    Having COUNT(CategoryId) > 1
)
```

So I am able to group the CategoryId's by ParentId, but still not sure how to increment the new rows for each unique ParentId

Here is what the results look like

[image: query results]

So the CategoriesSort Table would look like this

```
Category ID    ParentID    Sort
1807           2546        1
2000           1999        1
2001           1999        2
2005           3637        1
2008           3637        2
2009           3637        3
```

We are storing the Sort value so that Items can be arranged how another team wants them to be viewed online.

Comment: why don't you update the table with calculated `sort` value after all the rows are inserted?

Comment: If you want 1807 to have a sort then you don't wand Having COUNT(CategoryId) > 1.  And why store something in a table that can be easily derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) and a view, rather than storing the value:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.SOLCategoriesSort 
AS
    SELECT  CategoryId,
            ParentId,
            Sort
    FROM    (   SELECT  CategoryId, 
                        ParentId,
                        NumberOfItems = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId),
                        Sort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY CategoryID)
                FROM    SOLCategories
                WHERE   CategoryId > 0 
                AND     ParentId > 0 
            ) AS t
    WHERE   t.NumberOfItems > 1;
GO
```

This will mean that you don't need to recalculate the `Sort` column for every insert/update/delete on the base table.

**EDIT**

The expected output does not seem to match up with your attempt, so I am not sure which is correct, in the attempt you have the following:

```
AND  ParentId IN (
    Select ParentId
    From SOLCategories
    Group by ParentId
    Having COUNT(CategoryId) > 1
)
```

Which implies you only want to apply a `sort` to categories where the parent has more than one child, however in your sample data you include:

```
Category ID    ParentID    Sort
1807           2546        1
```

And 2546 is the parent for only one category. If all categories should be given a sort, then you can simplify the view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.SOLCategoriesSort 
AS
    SELECT  CategoryId, 
            ParentId,
            Sort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY CategoryID)
    FROM    SOLCategories
    WHERE   CategoryId > 0 
    AND     ParentId > 0;
GO
```

**EDIT 2**

Since you want to store the sort order so it can be manipulated, I don't think you need a separate table for this, you can simply add a column to `dbo.SOLCategories`. The approach I usually use for scenarios like this is a nullable column to store the sort order:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SOLCategories ADD Sort INT NULL;
```

The column `Sort` can be modified, but is nullable so that it doesn't require triggers, or other actions to maintain. I would still use a view to maintain this, but I would add the new Sort Column to manage the ordering in the row_number function:

```
Sort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY -Sort DESC, CategoryID)
```

I have used `-Sort DESC` to ensure that actual values are sorted before `NULL`, and also that 1 is given precendence over 2.

So taking the following example:

```
Category ID    ParentID    Sort
2005           3637        NULL
2008           3637        NULL
2009           3637        NULL
```

The view gives:

```
Category ID    ParentID    Sort
2005           3637        1
2008           3637        2
2009           3637        3
```

Supposing you then want `2009` to appear first, you can set this `Sort` in this to 1:

```
UPDATE  dbo.SOLCategories
SET     Sort = 1
WHERE   CategoryID = 2009;
```

So your data is now:

```
Category ID    ParentID    Sort
2005           3637        NULL
2008           3637        NULL
2009           3637        1
```

Which changes the view ordering to:

```
Category ID    ParentID    Sort
2005           3637        2
2008           3637        3
2009           3637        1
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a20c4/1)**

Comment: @Downvoter - Care to comment? In what way is this answer not useful?

Comment: I gave it a +1 a while ago. And it is a more complete version of an answer with +3.

Comment: Hey Gareth, I haven't worked with Views very much.  So with using this approach, the view, would I perform CRUD operations on the View? Or the original table?

Comment: Yea that was a mistake on my part.  They should only have a sort value if there is more than 1 row for that given ParentId.

Comment: This answer is really great. thanks for all of the detail Gareth, and the SQL Fiddle.  I will try to implement it in the fashion that you have posted.  I'll post back here later and let you know how it is going. thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand the View... In the fiddle example you set 2009's sort to 1.  So then I set 2005's sort to 1.  The View knew to display 2005 first, and then 2009 as 2. but in the original table they both had a value of 1 for sort.  How does the view know which to display first??

Comment: If two categories with the same parent have the same value for `Sort` then it will sort these by `CategoryId` - so in the view no two categories with the same parent can have the same value for sort.

Answer (score 3):

First of all - why do you need to store this information in the CategoriesSort table at all?

A simple query on your Categories table could give you the answer you need, whenever you need it (and the performance should be pretty good too):

```
SELECT CategoryId, ParentId, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentId ORDER BY CategoryId) AS Sort
FROM
    Categories
```

If you really need to update the values in a separate table, just use the query above as the source of a MERGE statement, to insert/update the values whenever a row is inserted/updated in the Categories table.

Comment: We are storing the Sort value so that another team can arrange the order in which the items should be viewed.

Comment: In that case, use the query above to initially populate the CategoriesSort table. Then, everytime a new row is inserted into Categories, do something like this: `MERGE CategoriesSort AS Tgt USING
(SELECT CategoryId, ParentId, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentId) AS Sort FROM Categories WHERE CategoriId = <<category id of inserted record>>) AS Src
ON Src.CategoryId = Tgt.CategoryId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Tgt.Sort = Src.Sort
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (Src.CategoryId, Src.ParentId, Src.Sort)`